# Получить нужный текст

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Каким образом из строки `http://site.ru/link/s-680.jpg` получить только **s-680.jpg**. То есть, нужно только то, что находится перед последним символом **/** , так как текст в строке может быть разный.

Буду благодарен за информацию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно так

```php
<?php
$str = 'http://site.ru/link/s-680.jpg';
$array = explode('/', $str);
echo end($array);

// Вариант еще короче
$str = 'http://site.ru/link/s-680.jpg';
echo preg_replace("/^.*\/(.+)$/", "$1", $str);
```

Comment: `end(explode(...))` делать нельзя, потому что в end массив передается по ссылке. Поправил код.

Answer (score 3):

Используйте функцию pathinfo(), например:

```
print_r(pathinfo('/some/path/.test'));

Array
(
    [dirname] => /some/path
    [basename] => .test
    [extension] => test
    [filename] => 
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно и так

```
echo basename('http://site.ru/link/s-680.jpg');
```